# Sending headers for every part in multipart request

Tags: postman

I would like to send specific headers with every part in multipart request. Example below.

```
POST /api/my_resource
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryFVgKJdNNgzHnHwTz

[Fri Aug 02 10:25:23 CEST 2019]
------WebKitFormBoundaryFVgKJdNNgzHnHwTz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field"
My-Custom-Header: value

some data ...
------WebKitFormBoundaryFVgKJdNNgzHnHwTz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="my_file.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
My-Custom-Header: value

Lorem ipsum ...
```

How to do this using postman?

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4 for the `multipart/form-data` specs - it does not allow for custom headers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @wezten. I went throught documentation you mentioned but I couldn't find information that custom headers are not allowed in multipart parts.  Can you point me to the paragraph which says that? BTW, you can access part's custom headers using standard java servlet api.

Comment: The protocol lists the optional & required headers. Any header not listed is not required and not optional, meaning that using it will cause the data to not conform with the protocol.